# Laravel - custom id

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make my custom ID for table `posts`. And I found haruncpi laravel id generator and I installed it with this command.

`composer require haruncpi/laravel-id-generator`.

After that I add `use Haruncpi\LaravelIdGenerator\IdGenerator;` to my `PostsController`. And now i need to add this snippet to my model.

`$id = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'posts', 'length' => 10, 'prefix' =>'INV-']);`

But I don't know where and how... Maybe in `public function store()` or somewhere else? Please help!
I just want my id to be like:
INV-000001
INV-000002
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel models has a `boot()` method, where you can register calls related to your model. Therefor you can subscribe to the creating event, which will fire before the model is saved and you can mutate the model in the process.

So in your Post.php model, add the following.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->id= IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'posts', 'length' => 10, 'prefix' =>'INV-']);
    });
}
```

And as long as you utilize basic `Laravel` functionality, it will add the id to the model.

Comment: It shows me error ```A non-numeric value encountered``` now? Any solutions ?

Comment: Is your id column an int?

Comment: Yes it is, ```$table->bigIncrements('id')```

Comment: I changed to ```$table->string('id')``` and it is working!

Comment: Super if it works please accept it as the answer :)